# TFS REST API: From inside VSTS extension, Check-In to another source control

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-2015, azure-devops-rest-api

From my TFS extension, using TfvcHttpClient, I am able to check-in files to the same TFS where the extension is installed, but how can I check-in to other TFS' tfvc?

```
import TFS_VC_TfvcRestClient = require("TFS/VersionControl/TfvcRestClient");
var tfvcApi = TFS_VC_TfvcRestClient.getClient();
```

Can I somehow tell getClient() to use another serverUrl?

Edit: Added check-in code to be more specific

```
function checkinXML() {
    $(".vlc-tvc").hide();
    $(".vlc-button").hide();
    var changeset/*: TFS_VC_Contracts.TfvcChangeset*/ = {
        accountId: VSS.getWebContext().account.id,
        //author: {
        //    id: VSS.getWebContext().user.id,
        //    displayName: VSS.getWebContext().user.name,
        //    uniqueName: VSS.getWebContext().user.uniqueName,
        //    //url: how to get URL?
        //},
        //changesetId: currentChangeset ++?,
        //checkedInBy: {
        //    id: VSS.getWebContext().user.id,
        //    displayName: VSS.getWebContext().user.name,
        //    uniqueName: VSS.getWebContext().user.uniqueName
        //    //url: how to get URL?
        //},
        //checkinNotes: [],
        //collectionId: collectionID,
        //teamProjectIds: [projectID],
        //commentTruncated: false,
        //createdDate: null,
        //hasMoreChanges: false,
        policyOverride: {
            policyFailures: []
        },
        //url: how to get URL?
        //workItems: null,
        //_links: null,
        comment: VSS.getWebContext().user.name,
        changes: [
            {
                //mergeSources: [],
                //pendingVersion: {},
                changeType: TFS_VC_Contracts.VersionControlChangeType.Add,
                item: {
                    //changeDate: {},
                    //deletionId: {},
                    //hashValue: {},
                    isFolder: false,
                    isBranch: false,
                    isPendingChange: false,
                    //size: {},
                    //_links: {},
                    //version: {},
                    contentMetadata: {
                        contentType: "text/xml",
                        encoding: 65001
                        //    fileName: "D.USD.xml",
                        //    extension: ".xml"
                    },
                    path: sourceControlPath //+ "/" + projectName + ".xml"
                },
                newContent: {
                    content: newXML,
                    contentType: TFS_VC_Contracts.ItemContentType.RawText
                },
                //sourceServerItem: sourceControlPath + "/" + projectName + ".xml"
            }
        ]
    };
    statusindicatorObject.startWait();

    tfvcApi.getItem(changeset.changes[0].item.path).then(function (result) {
        changeset.changes[0].changeType = TFS_VC_Contracts.VersionControlChangeType.Edit;
        changeset.changes[0].item['version'] = result.version;
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }).then(function () {
        tfvcApi.createChangeset(<any>changeset/*, projectName*/).then(function () {
            statusindicatorObject.endWait();
            var successCheckInDialog = VSS_Controls_Dialogs.show(VSS_Controls_Dialogs.ModalDialog, {
                title: "XML Check-In "  + sourceControlPath,
                content: $("<p/>").addClass("confirmation-text").html("Successfully checked-in XML to <b>" + sourceControlPath + "</br>."),
                useBowtieStyle: true,
                buttons: {
                    "OK": function () {
                        successCheckInDialog.close();
                        successCheckInDialog.dispose();
                    }
                }
            });
            $(".vlc-button").show();
            $(".vlc-tvc").show();
        }, function (error) {
            statusindicatorObject.endWait();
            var failureCheckInDialog = VSS_Controls_Dialogs.show(VSS_Controls_Dialogs.ModalDialog, {
                title: "XML Check-In " + sourceControlPath,
                content: $("<p/>").addClass("confirmation-text").html("Check-In failure: <b>" + error + "</b>!"),
                useBowtieStyle: true,
                buttons: {
                    "OK": function () {
                        failureCheckInDialog.close();
                        failureCheckInDialog.dispose();
                    }
                }
            });
            $(".vlc-button").show();
            $(".vlc-tvc").show();
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know a bit about the overall scenario, because it is a very steep path.

Comment: Added some code

Comment: Your chance is to split the work between the extension (Javascript on the client) and some other utility code that do the heavy lifting on the client (but not in the browser) or on the server.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.

The connection uses an implicit authentication token that is valid only for the TFVC specified in the build definition.

This means that you have to obtain a second token explicitly, e.g. passing a PAT through a variable. Furthermore you cannot use the same workspace for another TFVC mapping but you must use two workspaces (it is a grunge work to define and use one) and copy files over.

Comment: Giulio, are you thinking of a build task extension? I`m not using build definitions or the new tfs build. My extension is just a typescript written hub page which gets files manipulates the xml and checks it back in. No workspace mappings, just file streams

Comment: Those API are no use for you: you can only check-in a _merge_, which happens server side, and nothing else. No REST api offers what you want.